# Why does my Update Manager keep crashing and apt-get segfaulting?

Tags: 12.04, updates, apport

Whenever update manager goes to check for updates - when done both manually and automatically - update manager crashes, and when I go to report the error, apport crashes too (apport also crashes when I try to report errors from other processes).  Also, when I use apt from the command line to install programs, it stops while reading the package lists, and says: Segmentation fault (core dumped).
**Solved**
I copied the apt subsystem out of my other Ubuntu install - works perfectly now.  I guess one of the package lists was corrupt, so that was causing the segmentation fault.  Could probably have achieved the same results by deleting the package lists in /var/lib/apt/lists, but I was bored >_>

Comment: Try with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and post the output.

Comment: Run the memory test from the Ubuntu Live CD/USB -- this reeks of bad RAM.

Comment: If you have found a solution, you can post and answer and accept it--this is the norm here

Comment: I have the same problem. What do you mean exactly to do by copying "the apt subsystem"? Is that a directory? if so, where?